# Prevent line break for lengthy text when generating YAML using Python

Tags: python, yaml, rasa, rasa-nlu, ruamel.yaml

I am trying to generate YAML similar to following format:

```
version: '3.1'
nlu:
- intent: anxiety_intent
  examples: |
    - my anxiety has been overwhelming lately.
    - i am struggling with my stress levels right now.
    - i'm having a bit of a crisis and not serious, but need to talk just a very long panic attack.
```

So far I am able to generate the YAML as follows:

```
version: '3.1'
nlu:
- intent: anxiety_intent
  examples: |
    - my anxiety has been overwhelming lately.
    - i am struggling with my stress levels right now.
    - my anxiety has been bad.
    - i'm having a bit of a crisis and not serious, but need to talk just a very long
      panic attack.
```

As you can see, the last sentence is lengthy and gets wrapped to the next line. How can I prevent that?

There is a google sheet from where I am pulling the data. A sample would look like:
[image: Sheet data]

This is my approach so far:

```
import yaml
from yaml.resolver import BaseResolver

class AsLiteral(str):
  pass

def represent_literal(dumper, data):
  return dumper.represent_scalar(BaseResolver.DEFAULT_SCALAR_TAG, data, style="|")

yaml.add_representer(AsLiteral, represent_literal)

##########################################################################
###################### INTENT FUNCTIONS ##################################
##########################################################################

def generate_intent_dict(worksheet):
    rows = worksheet.get_all_records()
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
    all_intent_list = {col : [x for x in df[col].values if x != ''] for col in df}
    filtered_intent_list = {k: v for k, v in all_intent_list.items() if v}
    return filtered_intent_list

def generate_yaml_specific_intent_dict(intents_dict):
    yaml_dict = {
        "version" : "3.1",
        "nlu" : [
        ],
    }

    for k, val in intents_dict.items():
        d1 = dict()
        d1['intent'] = k 

        info_str = AsLiteral(yaml.dump(val))
        d1['examples'] = info_str
        yaml_dict['nlu'].append(d1)
    return yaml_dict
    


##########################################################################
###################### FILE SAVING FUNCTIONS #############################
##########################################################################

def yaml_specific_intent_write(yaml_dict, path, fname):
    with open(os.path.abspath(path + fname), 'w') as f:
        yaml.dump(yaml_dict, f, sort_keys=False)
```

How can I dump the data without wrapping/line break?

Comment: Never include promises about appreciation in a post, reading that wastes every future readers time. Keep it crisp. On the other hand always include a question (i.e. a sentence with a question mark), in the posts text (do not hide it in the title). Appreciation is expressed by upvoting c.q. accepting relevant answers, and possible a  comment below the answer (but that is not necessary).

Answer (score 0):

The output that you show has the lines from the google sheet, preceded with a dash, in literal style scalar that
is the value for the key `examples`.
So you have to create something that gets dumped as such a scalar.

If you can't find how to do that, the
best thing to do is load the expected YAML document and inspect the data structure. You will see that
the value for `example` is a `LiteralScalarString`, so that is what you need to create.

In the following I am leaving out the filtering:

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

google_sheet = """\
anxiety_intent
my anxiety has been overwhelming lately.
i am struggling with my stress levels right now.
my anxiety has been bad.
i'm having a bit of a crisis and not serious, but need to talk just a very long panic attack.
""".splitlines()
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.width = 30 
data = {
    "version" : "3.1",
    "nlu" : [],
}

nlu = {}
examples = ""
for idx, line in enumerate(google_sheet):
    if idx == 0:
        nlu['intent'] = line
    else:
        examples += f'- {line}\n'

nlu['example'] = ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.LiteralScalarString(examples)
data['nlu'].append(nlu)


yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
version: '3.1'
nlu:
- intent: anxiety_intent
  example: |
    - my anxiety has been overwhelming lately.
    - i am struggling with my stress levels right now.
    - my anxiety has been bad.
    - i'm having a bit of a crisis and not serious, but need to talk just a very long panic attack.
```

Lines in `LiteralScalarString` are not wrapped, if too long. But if some other line would be, adjust `yaml.width` to something
large (default is 80 columns).